# Changed RecyclerView value runtime

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-checkbox

[image]I want to make my recyclerView row get Update on checkbox selected value

Example If i want to divide 1000 in 10 person , when i am unselect 1 person then 1000 get divide by 9 and so on .All changes will be seen on screen .Like SplitWize app

[image]

Comment: Have you tried it after setting `setOnCheckedChangeListener` for CheckBox?

Comment: You shouldn't do that inside the `RecyclerView`. You should modify the value of your objects and then call `notifyDataSetChanged();` on your adapter.

Comment: yes i have tried but  all value not changed.If you have some idea please share with me

Comment: Try to add some code snippets, or simple drawings/mockups of what you want.

Comment: Hi Thomas i have added two screen i want like that

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure to understand the point of your question. But you can try something like that:

1. Set a `setOnCheckedChangeListener` on your checkboxes.
2. In this, call a method that do the math, depending on how many checkboxes are checked.
3. Then, `setDueMoney(int money)` (or something like that) on every `List<...>` item. The same list your adapter uses.
4. Then `adapter.setNotifyDataSetChanged();`